# How to/When sync gmail contacts with ubuntu one?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, contacts, gmail

Will it be possible to sync my gmail contacts with Ubuntu One, like we can do this with contacts from Facebook? There is some sentence in Ubuntu One preferences which suggests that we can do it already. I want to sync my contacts from gmail, not import these via Evolution or .csv file. I can't find anything about syncing gmail contacts in tutorials or FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed being worked on. I hope we can get one-way sync for Google contacts on production within the next 2 months, and two-way sync shortly after that.

So, soon  :)

Comment: In the Ubuntu one desktop client it says that it is possible, but I can not find it on the online dashboard. Any news?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+bug/468122) on this issue - good news, its in progress.  However no idea as yet, when this will land.  Maybe in 11.10.

Comment: 12.04, maybe? The linked bug report last saw activity back in early October and the New Year is almost upon us now.